# Did Tyrion even have the authority to do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S08E04 (The Last of the Starks) when Tyrion and Jaime are confronted by Bronn, Tyrion attempts to evade poetic justice by offering Bronn Highgarden. ***Was it even within Tyrion's power to give away Highgarden?***

---

**Follow up question:** Why would Bronn even risk waiting around to see how things play out? Based on his demeanor during that conversation, he seemed pretty pissed that all he has to show for serving the Lannisters is a lousy title. So, why wouldn't he just take bird in hand and collect the reward from Cersei instead of risking Tyrion dying before all of this is over? I mean, Tyrion even mentioned to him that all of this means nothing until they [the North] take over King's Landing, but it didn't really seem to faze Bronn.

Comment: The hand speaks with the King's/Queen's voice and generally they have more or less full liberty in governing how they see fit depending on the temperament of the monarch (Compare a tireless King like Jaehaerys I to apathetic ones like Robert Baratheon). In the monarch's minority or absence the Hand and Regents hold full authority but otherwise they must need to consult with the Monarch and get the Royal assent. So in other words, Whether Tyrion had the authority or not, that depends on Daenerys. She may overrule Tyrion if she wants, she may let it slip by.

Comment: Needs to be said however, Highgarden is a highly lucrative prize that Daenerys can use to break away powerful supporters from Cersei's camp. Tyrion handing it over to a lowborn cut-throat, with no army or power mind you, without so much a 'by your leave, your grace' would hardly sit well with Dany.

Comment: @Aegon while I fully agree that highgarden could a good reward for a powerful noble house who would switch side, same thing can be said for storm's end. Sure, having a Baratheon ruling it may encourage vassals to bend the knee, but it's still an entire kingdom given to a bastard

Comment: Also, Riverrun (even more with the Riverlands) is also a highly lucrative prize that Cersei can use to break away powerful supporters from Dany's camp

Comment: @Kepotx Well so far Cersei doesn't have any potential targets. Daenerys relied on Foreign troops before. Highgarden and Dorne swore to her for their own grievances against Lannisters. Tyrells are no more and Cersei can certainly entice other Reachmen with the same prize, Highgarden. Obviously she can dangle Riverrun to try and rally Riverlords but Riverlanders are done imo, they're worst hit by the war and I'd be surprised if they manage to muster more than 5-8k men. Remember Ser Edmure Tully is missing, he might turn up and take Riverlands back, he'll naturally be more inclined towards Dany

Comment: @Kepotx for Gendry meh, let's not even talk about that haha but I guess given how Baratheons are all dead and how Stormlords have always been fiercely loyal to the Baratheons (Baratheons are after all heirs to the Storm Kings too), I wouldn't be surprised if they preferred a legitimised bastard Baratheon to some unknown lordling who doesn't know the land or is upjumped.

Comment: Your "follow up question" makes this quite a little broad by confusing two entirely unrelated questions into one. Maybe you can connect the questions to each other a little more or turn it into one that fuses both of them?

Comment: He's not saying "I will give you Highgarden," he's saying "I will do everything I can to advocate for this."  Given his considerable influence and keen mind, Bronn trusts that it will happen if he commits to genuinely supporting it.

Comment: He was facing a death threat. He could offer whatever he wanted, why not the iron throne? It didn't have any legal binding.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Sure thing, I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### The goal was not only to get a better castle but to be sure to have one, whoever wins

Dany might lose, Bron can still kill Tyrion and Jaime, so he gets Riverrun (which is, by the way, a really good offer: the castle have a great defensive value, between two rivers).

He is taking a risk, as Tyrion and Jaime could die before Bronn can kill them himself, but the fact that if Cersei loses, he would still be rewarded is way better at his eyes.

### Can Tyrion give Highgarden?

While he is not King, remember that he is the hand of the Queen, a very prestigious title, closer adviser of the King/Queen who rules with him. Sometimes, he is even more powerful than the King, like with Robert Baratheon who didn't like to rule and delegate this nasty task to his hand.

While Dany can, of course, put veto on Tyrion's decision if she considers this title would fit better another noble, it is not idle talk by someone without any power

Comment: Also note that it's not impossible that Tyrion intends to leave the final decision up to Dany. When Tyrion informs her of the deal (whenever that is), Dany is still able to outright refuse (and possibly kill Bron if he seems like an active threat) if she wants. Tyrion is likely not going to be in trouble for proposing a deal that Dany can revoke without any real consequences, especially if it was made to (temporarily) save his and Jaime's life.

Comment: One small correction, Riverrun is not currently the capital of the Riverlands in the show canon. Littlefinger was appointed Lord Paramount of the Riverlands at the same time he was awarded Harrenhall by the Lanisters. As such, failing any other changes, if Cersei wins Harrenhall will still be the capital.

Comment: `While Dany can, of course, put veto on Tyrion's decision` and if that were to happen, it wouldn't be Tyrion's fault. He could declare Bronn as lord of Highgarden (appeasing Bronn), only to have it revoked by the Queen herself.